# I want to use full /56 or /64 subnet in squid proxy change on every request instead of 1 ipv6 only

Tags: proxy, squid

I want squid proxy to use full /56 or /64 IPv6 subnet instead of one Ipv6

I have two servers with squid proxy installed and my servers have been assigned with /56 and /64 ipv6 ranges

But on both servers when I curl request using squid proxy server I am only getting one Ipv6.

I want the ipv6 to change to a different one from the subnet on every new request.

How can this be done.

I have seen people do rotating IPv6 on squid proxy, if that too is possible I would like to do. But my main goal is to have a new IPv6 address on every new request I send via squid proxy.

How to achieve this, please help me out!

Comment: I have a linode so I have assigned a /64 block of IPv6 from linode console now how to use them in squid proxy

Comment: https://github.com/BackInBash/RPIPv6 I have found this but don't exactly know how to use it